# docker apt-get install fails fetching a file

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gdal

I have the following commands in DockerFile

```
# Use the official image as a parent image.
FROM ubuntu:18.04
#FROM node:10.18.0


# Install Node.js
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  wget \
  build-essential \
  software-properties-common


# install node version 10.18, need to use this specific
# version since it is the version that works with mapnik

RUN wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.18.0/node-v10.18.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

RUN tar -xJf node-v10.18.0-linux-x64.tar.xz -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner \
  && rm node-v10.18.0-linux-x64.tar.xz \
  && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs \
  && node --version \
  && npm --version

# install gdal
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  gdal-bin \
  cmake \ 
  build-essential \
  git \
  ca-certificates \
  libgdal-dev
```

and it fails with the following error:

```
et:151 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 unixodbc-dev amd64 2.3.4-1.1ubuntu3 [217 kB]
Err:152 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgeos-c1v5 amd64 3.7.1-1~bionic0
  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.85), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:153 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 proj-data all 5.2.0-1~bionic0
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:154 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libproj13 amd64 5.2.0-1~bionic0
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:155 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgeotiff2 amd64 1.4.2-2build1+bionic0
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:156 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libogdi4.1 amd64 4.1.0+ds-1~bionic0
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:157 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libspatialite7 amd64 4.3.0a-5build1+bionic1
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:158 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgdal20 amd64 2.4.2+dfsg-1~bionic0
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:159 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 gdal-bin amd64 2.4.2+dfsg-1~bionic0
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:160 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgeos-dev amd64 3.7.1-1~bionic0
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:161 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgeotiff-dev amd64 1.4.2-2build1+bionic0
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:162 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libogdi-dev amd64 4.1.0+ds-1~bionic0
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:163 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libproj-dev amd64 5.2.0-1~bionic0
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:164 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libspatialite-dev amd64 4.3.0a-5build1+bionic1
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:165 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgdal-dev amd64 2.4.2+dfsg-1~bionic0
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Fetched 61.7 MB in 33s (1896 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/g/geos/libgeos-c1v5_3.7.1-1~bionic0_amd64.deb  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.85), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/p/proj/proj-data_5.2.0-1~bionic0_all.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/p/proj/libproj13_5.2.0-1~bionic0_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgeotiff-dfsg/libgeotiff2_1.4.2-2build1+bionic0_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/o/ogdi-dfsg/libogdi4.1_4.1.0+ds-1~bionic0_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/s/spatialite/libspatialite7_4.3.0a-5build1+bionic1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdal/libgdal20_2.4.2+dfsg-1~bionic0_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdal/gdal-bin_2.4.2+dfsg-1~bionic0_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/g/geos/libgeos-dev_3.7.1-1~bionic0_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgeotiff-dfsg/libgeotiff-dev_1.4.2-2build1+bionic0_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/o/ogdi-dfsg/libogdi-dev_4.1.0+ds-1~bionic0_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/p/proj/libproj-dev_5.2.0-1~bionic0_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/s/spatialite/libspatialite-dev_4.3.0a-5build1+bionic1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdal/libgdal-dev_2.4.2+dfsg-1~bionic0_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I am able to access the files directly, for example pasting this link in the browser, [http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdal/libgdal-dev_2.4.2+dfsg-1~bionic0_amd64.deb](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdal/libgdal-dev_2.4.2+dfsg-1%7Ebionic0_amd64.deb)  you will download the file.

This used to work, but it's failing now. Any ideas?

Comment: "Could not connect...connection timed out" sounds like a problem with your network environment.  It's not a programming-related problem that could be fixed and regression-tested.

Comment: the weird part is that all the other apt-get calls success

Comment: Maybe the IP `91.189.95.85 80` gets blocked on your end? In any case, your file compiles fine on my side.

Comment: really? you ran it?

Comment: yes I did indeed and it worked as expected

Comment: @Val the odd issue is that it should'nt have worked! I found the issue is related to the gis ppa. Unless the archive and ppa IP's for you is different maybe?

Comment: @Val also thank you for running and verifying the dockerfile I appreciate your help tremendously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the particular issue was not related to internet access, as apt-get update worked fine, the gis ppa is somehow broken and frankly you don't need it anymore with the 18.04 LTS image, maybe the default 18.04 image has been updated.

remove

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was that ipv6 was not enabled from my docker container AND the ppa in question (ondre/php) must have begun to enforce it. This cost me a week of work hitting my head against a lot of walls. I actually restarted my laptop so many times I ran into Ubuntu's infamous persistent low brightness bug - but that's another story. So after bandaging my head, taking a nap, getting some rest and prayer, this is what I did to fix the problem:

*Resources listed after*

1. Upgrade Ubuntu to latest version (I think this is optional - I was just going full hilt)
2. Purge and reinstall Docker to latest version (now 20)
3. Found my ipv6 settings on my modem and made sure they were working. (they were). Basically, ensure ipv6 works on the Docker Host
4. Stop docker. `systemctl stop docker`
5. Create the daemon.json file in `/etc/docker` and add the following contents:

```
{
  "data-root": "/home/user/docker/data",
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "fd00::/80"
}
```

The last 2 attributes are what you focus on

6. Restart Docker `systemctl start docker`. At this point, you should have no docker errors
7. Then, this is the key, enable ipv6 access from docker containers through the host: (run on host)

```
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s fd00::/80 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
```

8. Use any way you like to persist #7

Resources:

- [How to enable IPv6 for Docker containers on Ubuntu 18.04](https://medium.com/@skleeschulte/how-to-enable-ipv6-for-docker-containers-on-ubuntu-18-04-c68394a219a2)
- [Iptables reload/restart on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052919/iptables-reload-restart-on-ubuntu-18-04/1072948#1072948)
- [Enable IPv6 support](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/)

Comment: Thank you @ChukkyNze for the answer it is useful information